# SQL format number to a specific precision

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way (formula?) in SQL (specifically mySql) to format a number to have a number of significant digits?

So, for a precision of 5

```
54.1        => 54.100

0.00054321  => 0.00054321
```

Comment: No, there isn't any general solution.